# How can i define interface in x.y form in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to extend my lib's prototype, and the lib is writing by JavaScript.

Just like I have a module `X`, and a `Y` class under it.

What I want is to extends `Y` by:

```
X.Y.prototype.method = function() { ... }
```

This will work in pure JavaScript, but in typescript, it throw error. It seems I need to add interface for the `Y` module by:

```
interface X.Y {
    method(): any
}
```

However, it throw the following error:

```
error TS1005: '{' expected.
error TS1005: ';' expected.
```

I have no idea about this...
Can anyone help me ? Thanks !

### Update

Here is a minimal demo:

```
// index.html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="./x.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="./app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>


// x.js
var x = {
    y: function() { }
}

// x.d.ts
declare module x {
    export class y {}
}

// app.ts
interface x.y {
  test: () => void
}

x.y.prototype.test = function() {

}
```

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the issue.

Comment: But do you have the typings for you library already? TS can help you extend typings, but not the actual prototypes or other objects

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko why couldn't it?

Comment: because after you transpile typescript into javascript there will no traces of it left :-) It does so called static typing, which means it allows your dev environment to know more about types in your app and nothing more than that. Everything else is just regular javascript: prototypes, functions, classes and so on

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko the js code he posted works just fine in js. All he needs to do is to also tell the compiler that the new method was added to the interface.

Comment: how is X defined? with `namespace` ? or is it just a file you import with an import statement?

Comment: surely it works fine, just d.ts should be written for the module

`declare module 'module-name' { export.... }`

Comment: maybe I didn't get something!

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko See https://gist.github.com/jnizet/4e7947cd52edd53c589a7705de7074c6. main.ts extends the prototype of Y, defined in X.js. Hence my question: why couldn't it? As you said, in the end, it's just JavaScript. So it can do what JavaScript can do.

Comment: I've edited my answer below, the second part of it should do the job if I haven't messed up with the .d.ts file :-)

Comment: @JBNizet I've add my mininal in the update.

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this will help

```
// let's pretend this is our original lib
const X = function () { };


type ExtendedProto = {
  new (): {
    test: (arg1: string) => void;
  }
};

const Y = X as typeof X & ExtendedProto;

Y.prototype.test = function(arg1: string) {
  // console.log('test');
}

const y = new Y();
y.test('1');
```

or you could creating an index.d.ts file with approximately the following

```
// index.d.ts
declare module 'x-y-z' {
  export class X {}
}

// .ts file
import { X } from 'x-y-z';

class Y extends X {
   test() { console.log('test'); }
}

const y = new Y();
y.test();
```

Comment: Hi, I've add my minimal demo in the question.